# Export data from InfluxDb which is inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, export, influxdb

Is there a way to export the data from influxdb, which is inside kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backup [InfluxDB](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/tree/master/k8s/influxdb) data to your local computer

**1.** Navigate to the influxdb/scripts directory:

```
$   cd click-to-deploy/k8s/influxdb/scripts
```

**2.** Run the make_backup.sh script, passing the name of your InfluxDB instance as an argument.

```
$  ./make_backup.sh $APP_INSTANCE_NAME $NAMESPACE [BACKUP_FOLDER]
```

The backup is stored in the influxdb-backup directory on your local computer.